# Compute measurement sum of squares

Tags: variance

Kindly look at the image attached. It contains the data.

There are three sources of variation, as you can observe:

1. Due to Patients , that is (sum of squares patient) = 114.
2. Due to Observers, that is (sum of squares observers) = 20.
3. And finally, the Random  (sum of squares error) = 10??

I am not able to compute the Sum of squares Error. Please guide me.

When we compute the total sum of squares within, it comes as 30. This is understandable. In this case, that total sum of squares within is made up by observers and random error. The former I could calculate but the latter, I am not able to. Here is the sentence that might help in computing the SOS error:

Finally, the sum of squares (Error) is based on the difference between each individual value and its expected value calculated from the row and column means. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kweKE.png)

Comment: There's part of the question missing here in my opinion. But given the table comes from Health Measurement Scales: A Practical Guide to Their Development and Use (Streiner, Norman & Cairney 2015) and that's available on google books I suggest reading pages 164-167.

Comment: Hi, yes, you are right. I came across this in the book and could not follow it, hence asked.

Comment: then I suggest you follow the advice to understand how the expected values should be calculated as they give you the start of the sum of squares error calculation - I think that's the bit you need really... this is prob off topic for stack overflow anyway tbh